# Python3 turtle save code to file

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I'm new to the Python turtle library and I have a problem that confuses me a lot.
I can work with turtle in real time, but when I write a program and I save it to a file, I can't run it.
The code I have written follows below:

```
from turtle import *

turtle.Pen(9999999)
penup()
for i in range(16):
  write(i,align='center')
  forward(25)
goto(0,-5)
x=0
right(90)
for i in range(16):
  pendown()
  forward(400)
  penup()
  x+=25
  goto(x,-5)
```

but it didn't work at all.
It gave me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Nobody\Desktop\main.py", line 3, in <module>
    turtle.Pen(9999999)
NameError: name 'turtle' is not defined
```

I think it doesn't import turtle at all.

Comment: In addition to naming your file `turtle.py`, you also did not import the module as such. You imported all functions, etc., but not the module. Therefore, `turtle.Pen(9999999)` must be `Pen(9999999)`.

Comment: @DyZ, did you test this? On my system it generates `KeyError: 9999999` as 9999999 isn't the name of a turtle shape.

Comment: @cdlane I was more concerned with `turtle.Pen` vs `Pen`. 9999 is another error.

Comment: @DyZ, clearly, but when you say, "must be Pen(9999999)", you've commited yourself to that invocation.  Always worth checking code that's posted.

Answer (score 1):

You named your own file `turtle.py`

So your `main.py` is importing your own `turtle.py`, not python's `turtle` module.

Delete `turtle.py` from your desktop (and the `turtle.pyc` that was automatically generated).

```
from turtle import *
```

this line imports everything to the default module namespace, so you don't have to add `turtle.` prefix to anything

Instead of `turtle.Pen` you want just `Pen`

Comment: Alternatively just import the module itself like so: `import turtle`.

Answer (score 0):

> from turtle import *

Means literally: import all from the file turtle.py.
Python interpreter firstly checks in the current directory for any match with turtle.py and if not found anything, it will search inside library folders.

In your case, you are importing all classes, all functions and all global variables (at least not private ones) from turtle.py so you need to use

> Pen(9999999)

Instead of

> turtle.Pen(9999999)

Comment: Did you test this?  On my system it generates `KeyError: 9999999` as 9999999 isn't the name of a turtle shape.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a rework of your code that runs fine for me:

```
from turtle import *

speed('fastest')
penup()

for i in range(16):
    write(i, align='center')
    forward(25)

goto(0, -5)
right(90)

x = 0

for i in range(16):
    pendown()
    forward(400)
    penup()
    x += 25
    goto(x, -5)

hideturtle()

done()
```

If it runs for you, great.  If it doesn't, let us know the complete error you're getting as a comment follow on to this answer.  Make sure you don't have a personal turtle.py file, as @nosklo notes.

My advice is when it comes to invoking library functions, it's better to lookup rather than make up.